# Shellsort, 2.48^(k-1) vs Tokuda's sequence

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, shellsort

### Introduction

Shellsort is an interesting sort algorithm that I came across a while ago. The most amazing part is that a different gap sequences can significantly improve the speed of the algorithm. I did a few reading (not extensively) and it seem that Tokuda's sequence is recommendeded for practical applications.

Another interesting part is that the sequence of ratio 2.20~2.25 tends to be more efficient. So I did a small search thought the sequence of ratio from 2.20 to 2.50 and tried to search for which ratio that can performance averagely good. I come across this ratio: 2.48 that seem to averagely performance good in many different trials.

Then, I came up with sequence generator: 2.48<sup>k-1</sup> (lets call it 248 sequence) and tried to compare it with Tokuda's sequence. It turned out that they averagely equal in speed. 248 sequences tends to use slightly more number of comparison.

### Benchmark Methods

- Instead of using millisecond as a measurement, I use the number of comparision and number of swap.
- I did 100 trials each on the following array size (50,000; 100,000; 200,000; 300,000; 500,000; 1,000,000) and keep track of their number of comparison and number of swap.
- The following is my data ([here in CSV format](http://pastebin.com/XUQ7CqMN)).
- Full Code: http://pastebin.com/pm7Akpqh

### Questions

I know I might be wrong that is why I come here to seek for more opinion from more experienced programmers here. In case you don't get the question, here is my question in short:

- Does 2.48<sup>k-1</sup> is as good as Tokuda's sequence?
- If it is as good as Tokuda's sequence, would it be more practical to use it since 2.48<sup>k-1</sup> sequence is easier to generate than Tokuda's sequence.

---

```
248 Sequence:
  ROUNDUP ( 2.48(k-1) )
  eg: 1, 3, 7, 16, 38, 94, 233, 577, 1431, 3549, 8801, 21826, ...

Tokuda's Sequence
  ROUNDUP ( (9k - 4k) / (5 * 4k - 1) )
  eg: 1, 4, 9, 20, 46, 103, 233, 525, 1182, 2660, 5985, 13467, ...
```

---

As @woolstar suggested me to also test with edge cases such as reversed and sorted. As expectedly, 248 sequence is faster in edge cases because 248 sequence gap is larger so it moves the inverse faster.

---

**Shellsort Implementation**

```
public static int compare = 0;
public static int swap = 0;

public static bool greaterthan(int a, int b) {
    compare++;
    return a > b;
}

public static int shellsort(int[] a, int[] gaps) {
    // For keeping track of number of swap and comparison
    compare = 0;
    swap = 0;

    int temp, gap, i, j;

    // Finding a gap that is smaller than the length of the array
    int gap_index = gaps.Length - 1;
    while (gaps[gap_index] > a.Length) gap_index--;

    while (gap_index >= 0) {

        // h-sorting
        gap = gaps[gap_index];
        for (i = gap; i < a.Length; i++) {
            temp = a[i];
            for(j = i; (j >= gap) && (greaterthan(a[j - gap], temp)); j -= gap) {
                a[j] = a[j - gap];
            }

            // swapping
            a[j] = temp;
            swap++;
        }

        gap_index--;
    }

    return compare;
}
```

Comment: Can you quote the Tokuda's squence here? I don't know it.

Comment: Besides testing on random ordered data, test how your sequence does with edge cases like completely sorted, almost sorted, and reversed.

Comment: @JanDvorak, I have updated the Tokuda's sequence formula.

Comment: @woolstar, thanks for your idea. I will try with edge cases.

Comment: @woolstar, as I have tested, at the edge cases, 248 sequence run faster because the gap is larger than Tokuda's sequence.

Comment: Can you show benchmark implementation and concrete results?

Comment: @BartoszKP, sure, let me commenting the whole code and post it here.

Comment: @BartoszKP, I have added the full code and the full result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this reserach](http://sun.aei.polsl.pl/~mciura/publikacje/shellsort.pdf): *(Ciura, Marcin (2001) "Best Increments for the Average Case of Shellsort". In Freiwalds, Rusins. Proceedings of the 13th International Symposium on Fundamentals of Computation Theory. London: Springer-Verlag. pp. 106–117)* the dominant operation in shell sort for arrays with size with less than 10<sup>8</sup> elements should be the comparison operation, not swap:

> Knuth’s discussion assumes that the running time can be approximated as 9×number of moves,
>   while Figures 3 and 4 show that for each sequence the number of key comparisons is a better measure of the running time than the number of moves. The asymptotic ratio of 9 cycles per move is not too precise for N ≤ 10<sup>8</sup>, and, if some hypothetical sequence makes Θ(NlogN) moves, it is never attained. Analogous plots for other computer architectures would lead to the same conclusion.
>
> Treating moves as the dominant operation leads to mistaken conclusions
>   about the optimal sequences.

In this context the answer to your question is no: the 248 sequence is worse, because it uses more comparisons. You could consider also comparing your sequence with the Ciura's sequence presented in this article, as this research seems to prove that it's better than Tokuda's sequence.

Comment: It is hard to compare with Ciura's sequence because there is no known value after 701. Using (Ciura's sequence) 1, 4, 10, 23, 57, 132, 301, 701 to sort array of size 1,000,000 would be slower than Tokuda even I extend h(i) = 2.25 * h(i-1).

Comment: Tokuda tends to use 1% less comparison than 248 sequence. I have tested it with Knuth's sequence and Sedgewick's one, and 248 sequence use less comparison.

Comment: @invisal Oh right, didn't notice that Ciura's sequence doesn't have general form. Well, seems then you could possibly have a publication in Springer :)

Comment: well, I just use random  array for benchmark. I did not have any mathematical model to prove for all the cases. Sadly.

Comment: @invisal Good and thorough practical experiments also hold a scientific value :) And still you can try adding even minor theoretical analysis.